# Error in swift playground: Cannot assign value of type 'Int' to type '[Int]'

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop

```
var number: [Int] = [1,2,3,4]
var newArray: [Int] = []
for i in 0...number.count-1{

    newArray = number[i] * number[i+1]
}
print(newArray)
```

I want output like this: [1 * 2, 2 * 3, 3 * 4].

I just don't get it where is the problem...

Comment: Multiple problems: 1. you are assigning to newArray, not appending to it, hence type error. 2. You are not using `i` variable. 3. Your code tries to add `number.count` elems to newArray, but in expected result there are only `number.count - 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var number: [Int] = [1,2,3,4]
let things = zip(number, number.dropFirst()).map(*)
```

Whenever you need to turn something like [1, 2, 3, 4] into pairs (1, 2), (2, 3) etc, then the AdjacentPairs method is useful - in Swift Algorithms package - https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms/blob/main/Sources/Algorithms/AdjacentPairs.swift
Or you can `zip` a collection with its `dropFirst` for the same result.

And whenever you need to turn an `[A]`s into an `[B]`s then `map` with a function that turns As into Bs.  So in this example you want to turn an array of tuples of Int, like [(1,2), (2,3), (3,4)] into array of Int, like [2, 6, 12] by multiplying the 2 Ints together, so `map` with `*`

The benefit of writing it this way is you would avoid the issues with your array mutation, getting index values wrong, running off the ends of arrays etc, and it's often easier to read and think about if you express it without the indices and assignments.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that the compiler flags you is that you assign a single `Int` value to an array of `Int`. The following line will resolve that immediate issue:

```
newArray.append(number[i] * number[i+1])
```

This should pass compilation but then create a runtime error at execution. The reason is that when you try to fetch `number[i+1]` when `i == number.count-1`, you actually fetch `number[number.count]`. This entry does not exist with 0-based indices. To get 3 sums out of 4 array entries, your loop should iterate 3 times:

```
for i in 0 ..< number.count-1 {
```

Or, if you prefer closed ranges:

```
for i in 0 ... number.count-2 {
```

A more Swifty way would be to use `map`, as @Dris suggested. The return type for `map` is implicitly given by the result of the multiplication, so you can write:

```
let newArray = number.indices.dropLast().map { i in
    number[i] * number[i+1]
}
```

Comment: Both for loops would crash as well  if the collection is empty.

Comment: @LeoDabus Correct, both for-loops cannot be applied to arrays with 0 or 1 elements. One more reason to go to the `map`-based solution, which just returns an empty array in those cases.

Comment: Not sure why would you add those to your post

Answer (score -1):

You can use `map()`

```
let numbers = [1,2,3,4]
let newArray = numbers.enumerated().map { $1 * numbers[($0 + 1) % numbers.count] }
```

Comment: This will result in [1 * 2, 2 * 3, 3 * 4, 4 * 1], the last entry not being what the OP wants.

Comment: Me culpa, forget about the last entry, but it's just simply `newArray.removeLast()` - with `var` instead `let`

Answer (score -1):

May be you should not loop to count-1 but stop before and add result to array :

```
   for i in 0..<number.count-1 {

    newArray.append(number[i] * number[i+1])
}
```

Comment: This would crash if the collection is empty